# What is a DCA-Enabler

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

What is a DCA-Enabler? What is it used for?

I saw this expression on this side: https://www.dell.com/de-de/work/shop/workstations/mobile-precision-7760/spd/precision-17-7760-laptop/n006p7760emea_vivp?configurationid=83a8be52-288e-4d5b-bf8b-210d665256cf

Ubuntu® Linux® 20.04 mit DCA-Enabler
(Dell Technologies empfiehlt Windows 11 Pro für Unternehmen)

Answer (score 3):

[From Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/ja-jp/wyse-wms/wyse-wms_3.0_ag/dell-client-agent?guid=guid-ab6c0a82-f0be-4698-9654-b31802522d12&lang=en-us):

> Dell Client Agent (DCA) is a unified agent for Dell Hybrid Client management solutions. If you install DCA, you can manage Dell Hybrid Clients using Wyse Management Suite.
>
> DCA Enabler is a client agent for managing Ubuntu version 18.04 LTS 64-bit on OptiPlex 7070 Ultra devices. The Dell Hybrid Client software is preloaded with Dell Client Agent-Enabler (DCAE). DCA-Enabler allows you to do the following actions that are managed by Wyse Management Suite:
>
> - Registration
> - Deploy Real-Time commands (RTC)
> - Unregistration from the server
> - Deploy Standard Application Policy
> - Deploy certificate policy

The version of Ubuntu as well as the model of Optiplex is not set in stone, of course.

Comment: What's the advantage of having it while buying?

Comment: Thank you very much, now it's clear.

Comment: it seems its for companies and advanced users to run things from remote locations/ over the network (with proper credentials) @haerriz

Comment: So I can ignore this for personal use for web development ? Will there be any restrictions ? Can I upgrade it to 22.04 ?